# How to change selected segment color in SwiftUI Segmented Picker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to set the selected segment color in a SwiftUI segmented picker and change the text color to white.

I have tried both using the modifiers for the picker view and modifying the tint color from the appearance proxy. None of them seem to work, unfortunately.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PickerView: View {

    @State var pickerSelection = 0

    init() {
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $pickerSelection, label: Text("")) {
            Text("Active").tag(0).foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Text("Completed").tag(1)
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).foregroundColor(Color.orange)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this in SwiftUI, or should I just use the UISegmentedControl by using UIViewControllerRepresentable?

Comment: What should we do if we want to have different tint color for another segmented picker in the same view?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

## Native ( *but limited* )

SwiftUI is not currently supporting native SegmentedPicker styling (see the bottom of the answer for the working workaround). But there is a limited way to apply a color to the segmented picker using `.colorMultiply()` modifier:

[image]

---

## Full control using `UIAppearance`

`selectedSegmentTintColor` is available since beta 3 for changing the color of the selected segment.

For changing the `textColor`, you should use `setTitleTextAttributes` for `.selected` state and `.normal` state (unselected).

So it will be like:

```
init() {
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = .blue
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue], for: .normal)
}
```

[image: Segmented Controll]

Also as mike mentioned, you can set the background color too like:

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .yellow
```

[image: Background demo]

Also, don't forget you can set SwiftUI colors too! For example:

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor(Color.accentColor)
```

Comment: Note that there is no code completion for these properties, but if you type them they will compile

Comment: You can change the color of the unselected segments with UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue

Comment: Hey @mojtaba-hosseini @mike any idea how to have it be the `AccentColor`?

Comment: just set it like `UIColor(Color.accentColor)` @StuFFmc

Comment: Oh thanks @MojtabaHosseini I was actually doing `UIColor(named: "AccentColor")!`. I didn't know there's that convenient converter :)

Comment: Where do you put init in Picker declaration ?

Comment: @Hope inside any class that is being created in the flow

Comment: It is better to limit the use of the appearance. If the parent-view is specific enough, then it is not necessary to reset the appearance with nil. That can affect the other components in the app.
let appearance = UISegmentedControl.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyController.self])

Answer (score 8):

Recently I had a similar issue that I needed a custom `background` and `foreground` colors for `SwiftUI SegmentedControl` I've found this post that also was helpful, but I also wanted to share other solution that I've found and I'm using now.
There is a very nice package called [SwiftUI Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) that allows to, well...

> Introspect underlying UIKit components from `SwiftUI`

With this package I created the following `SegmentedControl`
[image]
With this code:

```swift
VStack {
    Picker("Activity view", selection: $selectedActivity) {
        ForEach(ActivityView.allCases) { activity in
            Text(activity.description)
        }
    }
    .introspectSegmentedControl { segmentedControl in
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .clear
        segmentedControl.tintColor = TCHColors.SegmentedControl.backgroundSelected
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentTintColor = TCHColors.SegmentedControl.backgroundSelected
        segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: TCHColors.SegmentedControl.selectedText
        ], for: .selected)
        segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: TCHColors.SegmentedControl.normalText
        ], for: .normal)
    }
    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
}
.padding(.horizontal, 16)
```

And you can use this package to access many other underlying components from SwiftUI.

Comment: I get an error "Cannot find 'TCHColors' in scope" can you update the code if you can tnx or just add comment to solve it please @Sangsom

Comment: Hey there, these are colors used from global app specific enum file, you just change to colors you want using UIColor instance, eg. UIColor.green.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a manual implementation of segmented picker functionality:

```
@ViewBuilder func viewSegmentedButtons(arr: [String], selIndex: Int, baseColor: Color, closure:@escaping (_ selectedIndex: Int) -> Void) -> some View {
    
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(spacing: 1), count:arr.count)
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 1.0) {
        ForEach(Array(arr.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, translation in
            Button {
                closure(index)
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(index == selIndex ? baseColor : Color(.systemBackground))
                        .cornerRadius(radius: index==0 ? cRadius : 0, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
                        .cornerRadius(radius: index==arr.count-1 ? cRadius : 0, corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight])
                    Text(translation)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(index != selIndex ? baseColor : Color(.systemBackground) )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .foregroundColor(baseColor)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cRadius)
            .stroke(baseColor, lineWidth: 2)
    )
    .font(.callout)
    .background(baseColor)
    .cornerRadius(cRadius)
    .padding(.bottom, 10)
}
```

Usage example:

```
@State private var levelIndex: Int = 0
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Level:")
        
        viewSegmentedButtons(arr: ["Easy", "Meduim", "Hard"], selIndex: levelIndex, baseColor: .orange) { selectedIndex in
            withAnimation {
                levelIndex = selectedIndex
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answered helped me, but there is something I would like to add. The color I used was an argument to the view, so placing these methods in an init did not allow me to access the color.

Alternatively, you can use an `onAppear` method directly on the Segmented Picker, like so.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PickerView: View {
    var color: UIColor   
    @State var pickerSelection = 0

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $pickerSelection, label: Text("")) {
            Text("Active").tag(0).foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Text("Completed").tag(1)
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).foregroundColor(Color.orange)
        .onAppear {
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = color
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution that works in SwiftUI:

```
init(){

    UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = .green
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .selected)

    }
```